# Disable primary/unique key ordering

Tags: php, mysql

I've noticed that mysql reorders the rows using primary or unique keys and stores them that way. Can I disable this ordering?

```
 id (prim)  │ column1 │ column2
────────────┼─────────┼──────────
            │         │
```

If I insert the array below  into the table above

```
$rows = [
    ["8", "a", "a"],
    ["4", "b", "b"],
    ["3", "c", "c"],
    ["5", "d", "d"],
];
```

I get the following

```
 id (prim)  │ column1 │ column2
────────────┼─────────┼──────────
  3         │ c       │ c         
  4         │ b       │ b         
  5         │ d       │ d         
  8         │ a       │ a
```

I thought using unique instead of primary would help, but it didn't. I still get the ordered rows. Isn't there a way to keep the rows' original order that is by insertion order?

Rows should be stored in their insertion order while having primary or unique keys.

```
 id (prim)  │ column1 │ column2
────────────┼─────────┼──────────
  8         │ a       │ a            
  4         │ b       │ b      
  3         │ c       │ c          
  5         │ d       │ d
```

If I don't use primary or unique keys, I get the desired result.

---

This table and the array are just for demonstation. In the actual table, I don't use auto increment or any sequential number/string for primary keys. Every row has a unique random identifier, e.g. `9Z4CQtVd8Z`. Having them sorted have no purpose/benefit. I'd like to keep the rows by their insertion order.

Comment: just use `order by` when doing a `select` ... don't rely on the random order that sql servers return things in if you don't, because its not the order they're stored in, its essentially random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which data is stored is not of any interest at all. And mysql and other databases do not offer any guarantee that it will store data in primary key order. You need to use the ORDER BY clause when you are retrieving the data.

If you insert a set of data and retrieve them without a specific order by it's most likely that it will be returned in the same order that you inserted. However if you delete a few rows after that, followed by a few more inserts, the default ordering will change.

Comment: I already sort the rows when I make a query, but time to time, I manually check the table using phpMyAdmin and seeing default the row order change made me curious. I guess I'm nitpicking :) _The order in which data is stored is not of any interest at all._ seems to answer the question.

Comment: Will do, but I hope you don't mind waiting a little to see if someone else has anything to say :)